# Can a function be parametrically polymorphic over a non-nullary type constructor?

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types

In Haskell, there are many examples of higher kinded polymorphism when dealing with ad hoc polymorphism, such as Monad and Functor. However, I cannot think of any examples of this for parametric polymorphism.

Is this possible, and if so, can I have an example of one which is useful?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe What do you mean by a functor with no content?

Comment: sorry I think I misunderstood your question - just forget my remark - I meant something like `data Const a = Const` this can be made an instance of `Functor` but the value constructor contains no information of `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still allow typeclass constraints, then the answer is, *sure*! E.g. I'd still call something like

```
normalise :: (Foldable f, Functor f, Fractional n) => f n -> f n
normalise v = fmap (/sum v) V
```

parametric polymorphism. But I suppose that's not what you have in mind.

Another thing that's obviously possible is to just contrain types to have a particular form `_ _`, like

```
hmap :: (f a -> f b) -> [f a] -> [f b]
hmap = map
```

This isn't exactly remarkable, but it could possibly be useful in some applications as a subtle hint to the type checker. In fact, this is one way you can solve the phantom argument problem: instead of

```
class LengthyList l where minimumLength :: l a -> Int
instance LengthyList [] where minimumLength _ = 0
instance LengthyList NonEmpty where minimumLength _ = 1
```

you might make the signature

```
  minimumLength :: p (l a) -> Int
```

aka

```
  minimumLength :: proxy (l a) -> Int
```

Thereby you still pass in the type-information of `l`, but guarantee that the implementation cannot try to evaluate the argument at runtime.

The [standard way](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.8.3/docs/Data-Tagged.html) to do this is however

```
  minimumLength :: Tagged (l a) Int
```

[or](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html)

```
  minimumLength :: Proxy (l a) -> Int
```

Generally though, there's nothing you could do with `f a` that couldn't also be done with `fa`, so essentially you could rewrite the type of any such higher-order parametric function to a first-order parametrically polymorphic one.

Comment: If you use `RankNTypes`, things change a lot!

Comment: @dfeuer: yes, but I don't see what specifically changes with relevance to this question.

Comment: You can express, e.g., `(forall a . f a -> g a) -> ...`.

Comment: Sounds exciting, but I still don't see where you're heading. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, is there no time you'd want to write a type signature which contains a type constructor as a variable, applied to a concrete type, e.g. `f Int`? Then it couldn't be rewritten to a single type variable.

Comment: @CameronMartin: yes it could, because without any knowledge of what `f` is, `f Int` is just as useless as `a` – you can pass such a value on as it is, but you can't do anything with it yourself.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ah ok, although you'd be making the type of the function less restricted. So basically higher kinded parametric polymorphism isn't of much use?

Comment: @CameronMartin without type classes, I don't see how it would be useful.

Comment: I added the stub of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You totally can do this. A type synonym pigworker is fond of:

```
type f ~> g = forall a . f a -> g a
```

This, for reasons I don't actually know, represents a natural transformation (whatever exactly that is) between functors `f` and `g`. But a function can take an argument of type `f ~> g` and apply it to as many types `f a` as it likes. Using non-regular types (specifically, higher-order nested data types, as Ralf Hinze, for example, explored in [Numerical Representations as Higher-Order Nested Datatypes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.46.571)), it could be applied to an unbounded number of different types.

A contrived example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeOperators #-}

type f ~> g = forall a . f a -> g a
data Two g a = Two (g a) (g a)
data Foo f a = This (f a)
             | That (Foo (Two f) a)

hello :: (f ~> g) -> Foo f a -> Foo g a
hello t (This fa) = This (t fa)
hello t (That buh) =
  That (hello (\(Two x y) -> Two (t x) (t y)) buh)
```

`hello` is polymorphic in the types `f` and `g`, each of which has kind `* -> *`. † I believe that converting this to use only types of kind `*` could require non-trivial refactoring.

†In fact, if you enable `PolyKinds`, `f` and `g` will each have a polykinded type `k -> *`.

Comment: Ok, but not we'd still need an example of a function that's polymorphic in `f` or `g`.

Comment: Ah, I think I know now what you mean. This _is_ nice. Doesn't typecheck though, as it is...

Answer (score 1):

One example I'm quite fond of is the `foldr` operator for lists indexed by their length: it is parametrically polymorphic over a predicate `p` of kind `Nat -> *` and guarantees that if you apply it to a list of length `m` then you get back a proof of `p m`.

This corresponds to this type:

```
foldr :: forall a (p :: Nat -> *).
         (forall n. a -> p n -> p ('Succ n)) ->
         p 'Zero ->
         forall n. Vec a n -> p n
```

This extra precision makes it possible to implement e.g. `append` using `foldr` rather than having to proceed by pattern-matching.

```
append :: forall a m n. Vec a m -> Vec a n -> Vec a (m :+: n)
```

I've uploaded [a complete gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/7167e30136a0b51865ca06f459b4a442) with all the right language extensions turned on and the code corresponding to these types in case you want to peek.

Comment: This feels insufficiently polymorphic, which allows for incorrect implementations mixing up vector elements. I'd have expected something more like `foldr :: (forall t ts . t -> p ts -> p (t ': ts)) -> p '[] -> HList xs -> p xs`.